# How to use conditional types to get type narrowing inside function body

Tags: typescript

I have a conditional type defined so that the second argument to my class constructor is constrained depending on the type of the first argument.

The type checker correctly identifies what I'm allowed when calling the constructor. However, inside my constructor I can't get the compiler to infer the type.

```
enum Type {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}
type TypeKeys<T extends Type> =
    T extends Type.A ? {a: number} :
    T extends Type.B ? {b: number} : never;

class TestClass<T extends Type> {
    constructor(type: T, data: TypeKeys<T>) {
        if(type === Type.A) {
            data.a // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'TypeKeys<T>'.
        }
    }
}

new TestClass(Type.A, {a: 10})

//Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: number; }'.
new TestClass(Type.B, {a: 10})
```

Is there a way to take advantage of type narrowing inside the constructor body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). Add shared property (`kind` of type `Type`) on both interfaces. That was TypeScript can "discriminate" type both inside of the constructor body and outside.

```js
enum Type {
    A = 'A',
    B = 'B',
}

interface A {
    kind: Type.A;
    a: number;
}

interface B {
    kind: Type.B;
    b: number;
}

class TestClass {
    constructor(data: A | B) {
        if(data.kind === Type.A) {
            data.a = 5;
        } else {
            data.a // Property 'a' does not exist on type 'TypeKeys<T>'.
        }
    }
}

new TestClass({ kind: Type.A, a: 10 })

//Argument of type '{ a: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ b: number; }'.
new TestClass({ kind: Type.B, a: 10 })
```

Comment: I've used discriminated unions in some of my projects, but I've found them to be buggy. I often have to explicitly cast to whatever type it's supposed to be.

Comment: I never encountered problems with discriminated unions. I am curious about this. Do you have any sample code which is problematic?

Comment: I haven't had issues with discriminated unions either. I decided to go with this approach, but I inlined the interface definitions while defining my original type. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, here's an old issue I opened on the typescript repo. Looking back, it looks like my issue was related to discriminated unions not working as expected with classes that implement an interface: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29178

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the compiler isn't yet smart enough to implicitly figure out that your code is safe. Here's what I think is going on:

When you create a new instance of the class, the compiler sees your type constraint and correctly prevents you from passing it the wrong data. However, inside your constructor, it looks like it doesn't propagate the constraint between the 2 different variables. I imagine possibly because it could get very complicated if you had multiple variables controlling what type your data is.

Typescript does have a thing called discriminated unions that is made for cases like this, although from personal experience I've found the auto type inference to be buggy and to not work at all in some cases. I've given up on getting it to auto-infer types, so I often cast to get things to work:

```
if (data.type === Type.A) {
    const dataA = <A>data;
    dataA.a;
}
```